# naming web service projects

Tags: wcf, web-services, rest, soap, asp.net-web-api

I have an c# visual studio solution.

Within it I have 2 different type of web serivces. 1 is WCF the other is Web Api.

I want to rename the projects in a standard way.

Should the wcf services be named "WCF", "SOAP"? And then for the web api project, should these be named "REST" or "HTTP"?

I want to name the projects consistently but not sure of the best naming style.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not a fan of either, personally i try to keep technology names out of my project names as things change over time.

Are both webservices for the same thing?

- Ideally if they are the same then try to retire one of them
- Combine them into one webservices project, allowing them to share code between themselves without adding yet another project to the solution (sorry i'm not a fan of having hundreds of projects in a solution).
- If you're stuck with 2 projects then name them Wcf and WebApi, because chances are if you ever try replace either technology you'll just create a new project.

I didn't go with SOAP for the WCF project, as WCF not limited to SOAP.  Then i just used the same convention for the WebApi project.

Comment: Yes, both return similar data but in different protocols and types. So 1 project is web api (http, rest) and the other is wcf (soap). What project names would you suggest to distinguish them?

Comment: WCF and WebApi are the frameworks used so its a good idea to name them based on that - thanks.